# please translate this python code into java for this question and explain what its internal works

Tags: java, python, algorithm, optimization

p.s. this is a codechef question, i coded this question in java and was partially correct, but so far I found this new code for optimisation but don't know pyhton.

Given integers `N` and `M`, find the number of ordered pairs `(a,b)` such that `1≤a<b≤N` and `((M mod a) mod b)=((M mod b) mod a)`. `t` is the number of test cases.

```
 N = 2304
 M = 23498


def fast():
    npairs = 0
    nfactors = [1] * (M + 1)
    for b in range(2, N + 1):
        npairs += nfactors[M - M % b]
        for i in range(0, M + 1, b):
            nfactors[i] += 1
    return npairs


def naive():
    return sum((M % a) % b == (M % b) % a for b in range(2, N + 1) for a in range(1, b))


print(fast(), naive())
```

Comment: One of the M's in the MOD case, should that have been an N?

Comment: @Surt No, we are just simplifying the mod operation and the last relation was that code and that it correct.

Comment: what about some kind of precomputation on values of x and a? values of x can only be 0...m; the most inner for could reuse some previously calculated data, and only calculate the mod for values not yet encountered of x and a.